# How to insert SVN path for Sql file in maven

Tags: mysql, maven, execution

this is a snippet of my current pom file which works fine :

```
<execution>
    <id>create-Myschema</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB</url>
        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
        <srcFiles>
            <srcFile>
                ${basedir}\target\classes\MyDB_schema.sql
            </srcFile>
        </srcFiles>
        <onError>abort</onError>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Now, instead of specifying the schema.sql to be picked from a target folder, I want to give an SVN path like so `https://intranetdomain/a/b/c/database/mysql/MyDB_schema.sql` 
MVN doc says nothing about this/I was not able to find it. Any and all permutations I try within `<srcFiles>` just keeps searching within the local project directories.
How can I tell maven to execute this sql from an svn location ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard about Maven being able to refer/operate on remote files like in your example.

If I were in your situation I would try to do the following:

1. Use [Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to call [Ant's Get task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) to download the file to the local target directory using its SVN url.
2. Refer to the downloaded (now local) file exactly in the way as you currently do it (using correct file path)

Make sure that 1. is invoked earlier in the Maven lifecycle than 2. (e.g. assign 1. to earlier phase, like `generate-resources`)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in some direction. I will work with this.